# Run JavaScript from vb.net code behind

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am trying to run some JavaScript from an event handler. Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub RecordBottomGridRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridView_Body.PageIndexChanging
    Dim scriptText As New StringBuilder()
    scriptText.Append("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("function RecordBottomGridRow() {")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('exp');")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("var expIndex;")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("for (var i = 0, im = elements.length; im > i; i++) {")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("var elementId = elements[i].id;")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("expIndex = elementId.substring(3);")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("}")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("var fundCode = document.getElementById('htmlFund' + expIndex);")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("var e = document.getElementById('exp' + expIndex);")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("document.getElementById('lastFundChosen') = fundcode.value;")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("document.getElementById('expOrColl').value = e.value;")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("alert(e.value);")
    scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    scriptText.Append("} </script>")

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "RecordBottomGridRow", scriptText.ToString(), False)
End Sub
```

Notice the "alert" at the end there. I run the code and the event fires, but no alert window pops up suggesting the JavaScript code did not run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does your javascript code look like in web browser? You can debug javascript code in browser.

Comment: Hit f12 after the page loads and debug the javascript, would be my first suggestion, fyi chrome is easier to debug in than IE

Comment: @user3715441 Did you call JavaScript function `RecordBottomGridRow`?

Comment: I tried in IE and Chrome. I see the script on the page but when I put a break point in and trigger the event the break point never gets reached.

Comment: What do you mean did I call the JavaScript function? I was told that RegisterStartUpScript() actually does the calling.

Comment: @user3715441 - `RegisterStartupScript()` will execute the code given to it. Your code, though, only creates a function. It never actually calls anything. Therefore, your function is never actually called.

Comment: Also why do I have to even create the JavaScript dynamically like that? Why can't I put it on the aspx page and just call it from the event handler? Documentation on this is very confusing.

Comment: Oh. Well I am interested in actually calling that function! How do I actually call it? The documentation said I had to create it dynamically like that. Do I just do a new line of code with RegisterStartupScript and call the function afterwards?

Comment: Adding the script like that is absolute horror, you could also simply include it inside your aspx page, and call it by it's functions name, or include it in a separate javascript file that gets loaded as AdditionalPageHead, or some other form, this way, it is useless, unmaintanable, and only serves to make it harder for you to correct it...

Answer (score 1):

You code just declares function, in essence it just adds to your page output:

```
function RecordBottomGridRow() {
.....
}
```

You need to add client-side code that actually call this function by name:

```
RecordBottomGridRow();
```

So in your case you can just replace line

```
scriptText.Append("} </script>")
```

with (to follow your format):

```
scriptText.Append("}")
scriptText.Append(Environment.NewLine)
scriptText.Append("RecordBottomGridRow(); </script>")
```

This code block finishes function declaration with "}" and then adds the call to function to actually execute it on client.